# How to get stripe customer id and stripe account id in the webhook request

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe webhooks, suppose a user pays to another user, is there any webhook which provides the customer id (who sent) and account id or destination (who received) both.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a user pays another user"? There isn't a concept of account-to-account payments in Stripe. You'd instead see Customers paying via Charges/PaymentIntents to specific Accounts (if you're using Stripe Connect) or to your own Account. Could you provide an example including who is paying who and for what types of services?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which of Stripe's payment methods you are using, but you can view the list of events and what they send [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types). If they send anything, it will be specified after the event's name with something like "`data.object` is an [account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#account_object)".